# Splitting a Pandas Column and Summing the Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this :

```
Time       Value
10:00       1|2
11:00       10|20|30
12:00       20|32
13:00       3|4|6|8|9
```

What I want is to have another Column "Results" which will have the sum of integer values on the "Value" column. The result will look like this:

```
Time       Value         Results
10:00       1|2             3
11:00       10|20|30       60
12:00       20|32          52
13:00       3|4|6|8|9      30
```

Whats is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `pd.eval()`:

```
df['Results']=pd.eval(df['Value'].str.replace('|','+',regex=True))
#OR
df['Results']=df['Value'].str.replace('|','+',regex=True).map(pd.eval)
```

OR

other way without using `pd.eval()` as suggested by [`@Jon Clements`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements):

```
df['Results'] =[sum(int(n) for n in val.split('|')) for val in df['Value']]
```

Comment: Or avoiding eval erring on the side of caution - the boring: `df['Results'] = [sum(int(n) for n in val.split('|')) for val in df['Value']]`

Comment: @JonClements Thanks sir for the suggestion but Sir it is 4*solwer than `pd.eval()`

Comment: How are you measuring that...? When I time it, the list-comp is in microseconds while the eval is in microseconds... they're massively different... (I'm getting the eval to be over 1000 times slower...)

Comment: I think the second one of those "microseconds" was supposed to be "milliseconds" @JonClements

Comment: You're correct Henry... my brain had a burp or something :p